# htaccess and IIS rewrite to map subfolder to one level up

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have this single page app made using AngularJS and it resides in the document root: http://example.com/

The API that Angular interacts with is created with CakePHP and is located in a subfolder called api. It's accessed via http://example.com/api/xxx.

Apart from acting as an API, the CakePHP application also has an administration backend. In the current URL structure, it's accessible via http://example.com/api/admin. To make it look neater I want users to be able to access it via http://example.com/admin.

What htaccess and IIS rule will I need to achieve this? I'll be testing on both platforms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `http://example.com/admin` I assume.

In htaccess you can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/admin(/?$|/.+) /admin$1 [QSA,L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=d8c07577-d6fb-501d-8e32-403531d471a1

Comment: Hi - thank you for your response. I'm plagued by a bigger issue. Could you perhaps take a look at it and shed some light? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583346/iis-showing-404-error-for-cakephp-routing-prefixes-for-instance-located-in-subfo